# Convert each pixel of a raster layer to polygon Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine

I am currently working on a raster of the United States that spans from the east coast to the west coast in Google Earth Engine. The raster was created using an image from the MODIS satellite at a resolution of 1 kilometer. I was wondering if it is possible to convert each pixel in the raster into a polygon to create a grid on the raster. If this is not possible, could you suggest any more effective methods to do this?

```
Map.addLayer(StateBorder, {color: 'blue'}, 'State Border');
Map.centerObject(StateBorder, 3);

// Import the LST image collection
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
  .filterDate("2020-06-01", "2020-08-31")
  .select('LST_Day_1km');

// Kelvin to Celsius
var modcel = modis.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});

// Image visualization
var mean = modcel.mean().clip(StateBorder);

// Add the mean layer to the map with a color palette
Map.addLayer(mean, {
  min: 0,
  max: 60,
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
}, 'Mean LST');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it is possible with 'coveringGrid' method for geometries and by using Modis projection as argument. Because your area is very huge, I implemented in following lines above method for a much smaller area inside USA.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-104.93181692852576, 38.47620742346919],
          [-104.93181692852576, 38.42888734452983],
          [-104.86040579571326, 38.42888734452983],
          [-104.86040579571326, 38.47620742346919]]], null, false);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["LST_Day_1km"],
                     "min":32.57,
                     "max":39.11,
                     "palette":["0c6cff","29ff10","faff04","ffc00c","ff4106"]};

// Import the LST image collection
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
  .filterDate("2020-06-01", "2020-08-31")
  .select('LST_Day_1km');

// Kelvin to Celsius
var modcel = modis.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});

print(modcel);

Map.centerObject(geometry, 13);

var img = modcel.first().clip(geometry);

Map.addLayer(img, imageVisParam, 'image');

var proj_modis = img.projection();

var grid_img = img.geometry().coveringGrid(proj_modis);

Map.addLayer(grid_img, {}, 'grid');

print(grid_img.size());
```

So, after running above [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/53c86f31832c776aae49918d52545f45) in GEE code editor, it can be appreciated in the produced Feature Collection (with only 61 features) the corresponding polygon grid.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer provided me with great guidance to complete my work :)